# Templates Django (Does not exist at/)

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, view

I'm trying to use the Django templates but i cant even display a simple html line i don't understand why...
I searched to resolve it but after many test, the problem remains.

**This is my structure:**

[image]

**My urls.py (which work i tried it with another fonction in views.py):**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',

         url(r'^$', 'home', name = 'home'),
         url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**My views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import Template , Context

# Create your views here.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'mysite/bap2pmonitoring.html')
```

**My setting file setting.py:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**My simple html doc:**

```
<h1> BAP2P Monitoring </h1>
```

**And the output finally my main problem :**

[image]

**And this is the traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.8.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/mysite/bap2pmonitoring.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/mysite/bap2pmonitoring.html (File does not exist)



Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/florian/Documents/mysite/polls/views.py" in home
  8.    return render(request, 'mysite/bap2pmonitoring.html')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  98.             template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  46.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: mysite/bap2pmonitoring.html
```

Out of ideas, i need your opinion please.
Thanks for your time

Comment: There's no reason for posting screenshots of text. Please just post the text.

Comment: Also, please post the actual traceback from the error page - click the "Switch to copy-and-paste view" and copy that text here.

Comment: Under TEMPLATES in the settings.py you are missing a parenthesis: 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P.S: Please edit your question instead of adding an answer to your question with a question :P

Coming to the error,

From your directory structure, you have two template directories, one in the main project and other in the polls app at **mysite/polls/mysite/**. Django is looking for templates in the project templates i.e.,

> /home/florian/Documents/mysite/templates/mysite/bap2pmonitoring.html

but you have your template in

> /home/florian/Documents/mysite/polls/templates/mysite/bap2pmonitoring.html

Put your templates in the main project template directory and it should work.

Answer (score 7):

`TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting is deprecated in django 1.8.  You should use the [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates) instead.

The `TEMPLATES` variable is exists in the default `settings.py` file so find it and alter the `'DIRS'` key:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        ...
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

It has a typo with the closing bracket. so the syntax error

use this

> 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

Answer (score 0):

you are missing to add your app in

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    **'mysite',**
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

in settings.py.