# Django 2.1.7 - "TemplateDoesNotExist at /munichlivingapp/seekers/

Tags: django

Django 2.1.7 - "TemplateDoesNotExist at /munichlivingapp/seekers/"

(The identical issue: [Templates Django (Does not exist at/)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188635/templates-django-does-not-exist-at) )

1)  The browser error message: [image: file1]

2)  My project file structure:

[image: file2]

3) The relevant part of my `settings.py` file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
        {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "django.core.context_processors.media",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I tried the 3 solutions I found on Stack Overflow, but  none of them worked.

(In the TEMPLATE_DIRS dictionary)

**1) Solution #1:**

```
'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
```

**2) Solution #2:**

```
'DIRS': ['templates'],
```

**3) Solution #3:**

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    ' /home/mycode/mysite/templates/',
 )
```

Comment: No image found on these links. Mention that you shouldn't post image for code or error log.

Comment: The images for 1) and 2) are now accessible.

Comment: add you views.py code where you mention the template name

Comment: https://ibb.co/4VbWQTc Note that the index function works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change `template_name='seekers_list.html'` to `template_name='munichlivingapp/seekers_list.html'`

Because you keep your template inside `templates/munichlivingapp` directory.

Comment: I get in the browser "ModuleNotFoundError at /munichlivingapp/seekers/ " on one line and underneath : "No module named 'django.core.context_processors' (additionally, in the terminal, I get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.context_processors')

Comment: what you try now?

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggested (i.e: "Change template_name= ... ")

Comment: use single code around the template name like in my answer?

Comment: You mean single quote ? This is what I have: def seekers_list(request,template_name='munichlivingapp/seekers_list.html'):

Comment: I get in the browser "ModuleNotFoundError at /munichlivingapp/seekers/ " on one line and underneath : "No module named 'django.core.context_processors' (additionally, in the terminal, I get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.context_processors')

Comment: https://ibb.co/njZGR1G this is what the browsers displays. The terminal just states: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.context_processors'
[30/Mar/2019 14:13:09] "GET /munichlivingapp/seekers/ HTTP/1.1" 500 117819

Comment: Use this in settigs.py `django.template.context_processors.media` instead of this `"django.core.context_processors.media"`

Comment: check where you use `django.core.context_processors` and remove this

Comment: Thanks ! The change template_name='munichlivingapp/seekers_list.html' as well as this: https://ibb.co/5Y8yf6b  made it work.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to let people know the problem has a solution, and as a thank you to Shafikur Rahman for taking the time to help you out.